# comparing two arrays and getting the number of same value

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to compare two arrays using PHP. for example.

```
$one = ["A", "C", "B", "D", "A", so on....]
$two = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "A", so on....]
```

What I want to do is to compare the arrays and get the number of items that are the same. I only compare items with the same index. this is what i had in mind

```
$ctr=0;
if ($one[0] == $two[0]){
    $ctr++;
}

if ($one[1] == $two[1]){
    $ctr++;
}

// so on.......

echo $ctr++;
```

but the above code is only appropriate for fixed length of array. could anyone one help me with the code?

Comment: You could use a foreach? http://php.net//manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php I'm a bit confused why you want to do it one by one.

Comment: Use `count` to get the length of the arrays and use that as the limit for a loop e.g. `$c = count($one); for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {}`

Comment: I think that it's better to sort the arrays first, then you can say if current element of both arrays are equals increment the result and iterate to the next position else, if the first is bigger increment the position for the second and so on.

Comment: I just put the code for better undestanding of what I wanted to happen. thank you for commenting though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can use loop instead of writing manually every condition. Demo:

```
$ctr = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($one); $i++) {
    $ctr += $one[$i] == $two[$i];
}
```

If you want to compare items with same index and length of array may differ, then,

```
$ctr = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < min(count($one), count($two)); $i ++) {
    $ctr += $one[$i] == $two[$i];
}
```

In the second piece of code we check till the end of the shorter array.

If you are not interested in order, matching at any place would do, try [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) And for additional with index checking [Array_intersect_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php)

Comment: thank you for answering. yes, i only compare items with the same index.

Comment: you can use array_intersect_assoc() while I've put the rewritten code too in top of my answer

Comment: hi @Fallen, the answer is correct but it is giving this error     Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: my mistake on the previous comment. this works for me. thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look

```
      $common = array_intersect($one,$two);
      echo count($common);

        // for key 

       $common = array_intersect_key($one,$two);
       echo count($common);
```

Comment: Assuming jonas wants the intersection, rather than (say) comparing answers of a multiple choice quiz against the correct answers

Comment: OP said,  `I only compare items with the same index`

Comment: @Vicky thanks for answering but I only have to compare items with same index.

Comment: @Vicky it is giving a different answer than expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to fulfill so:

```
$arr = array_intersect(array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),array('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'));
$array_length = sizeof($arr);
```

Hope this will help you.